# find_element_by_id is not able to locate the elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on Python with Selenium and I have created a web driver instance with the following command `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` and the web driver instance is created properly.

After this I am trying to get the element with id by: `str_title = driver.find_element_by_id("banner-section-title")`. But I am getting the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"banner-section-title"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpR0IR8T/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10299)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpR0IR8T/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10308)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpR0IR8T/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12282)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpR0IR8T/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12287)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpR0IR8T/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12229)
```

Comment: Are you sure an element with `id='banner-section-title'` exists on the page?

Comment: yes it is present and when i am trying to click the linkfrom my testcase using " Click Link    id=banner-section-title" it is working fine. But when i am trying to do the same thing from keywords file that is from .py file i am getting the above error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you have to be sure about the 'id' that you're looking for.
By the error that you posted seems that the element isn't found.

so you can try also to use the

```
driver.implicitly_wait(<seconds>)
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_id(<element>).is_displayed())
```

try this
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

```
page="www.yourwebsite.com"
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = self.driver
driver.get(page)
buffer = self.driver.find_element_by_id("foo")
```

then, if there is a button you could add the .send_keys(Keys.RETURN) (that's my example for login form)

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    username="myUserName"
    password="myPassword"
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_id("username").is_displayed()
    textUserName = self.driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    textUserName.send_keys(userName)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_id("password").is_displayed()
    textPassword = self.driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    textPassword.clear()
    textPassword.send_keys(password)
    btnLogin =  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Login']")
    btnLogin.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I hope this could help

Comment: the given code is working fine... but before creating web instanc only i am opening my url using Open Browser keyword. So i dont need to open the url after the web instance is created. Is there any other way to work withoiut including driver.get(page) and make the elements identify

Comment: if you don't open the url you cannot verify what is in, so the only way to check what is in the web page is open it with driver.get(page)